# How can we test an Enum like is valueOf()?

Tags: java, enums, value-of

G'day, ***errata*** ... My plan was as shown below.  This update is to clarify and apologise for a late night question.  The compile error was due to a problem elsewhere in the file.

Clarification: a simple Java **enum**, like this:

```
public enum ServiceSource
{
    NONE,
    URL,
    FILE;

}
```

Want to checking like, **isURL**():

```
 public boolean isURL(){

    return (URL == this);
}
```

This works (and *compiles*) ... There's no question -- Correctly answered by: **dasblinkenlight** and **Elliott Frisch**.  *Thank* you very much for your time.

see also:

- [Lookup enum by string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/java-convert-string-to-enum)
- [How to test enum types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079700/how-to-test-enum-types)

Comment: What's the exact compiler error that you get?

Comment: Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604424/java-convert-string-to-enum for an often-favorited answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is an instance method, you need to check that `this` is equal to `URL`, like this:

```
public boolean isURL(){
    return (URL == this);
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/pj3FWh)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have methods that are polymorphic - i.e. exhibit different behaviour for different instances (values) of your `enum` class, my preference is to override a common method:

```
public enum ServiceSource {

    NONE("no_value"),
    URL("url"){

        @Override
        public boolean isURL() {
            return true;
        }

    },
    FILE("file");

    private final String val;

    private ServiceSource(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public boolean isURL() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But for methods that check whether this is specific `enum` value then adding an `isXXX` method for each constant seems very wasteful. Really, the very reason to use an `enum`, is so that you can write

```
if(thing == ServiceSource.URL)
```

Elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, the correct method in your enum is to use `this` like so,

```
public enum ServiceSource
{
  NONE(   "no_value"  ),
  URL(    "url"       ),
  FILE(   "file"      );
  ServiceSource(String v) {
    text =v;
  }
  private String text;
  public boolean isURL() {
    return this == URL;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method on your Enum to check the value of itself like this:

```
  public boolean isURL(){
    return (URL == this);
  }
```

But it's hard to see the value in this approach since every Object has a built in equals() method that accomplishes the same thing.

```
if (serviceSource.equals(ServiceSource.URL)) { ... }
```

This would be a more common and obvious way to check the assigned value of an Enum variable (or any variable for that matter). Taking the first approach would require you to have a new isX() method on your Enum; every time you add an Enum constant, you would probably want a new method to accompany it.