# Testing a Condtional Based on Enum

Tags: java, junit, spock

Should I test every condition in unit test when the conditional is based on a method of an enum?

I mean if I have an enum with a lot of values, the unit test gets too big to reach all possible conditions.

Example:

```
public enum AnEnum {
   A(true), B(false), C(false), D(true);

   AnEnum(boolean isError) {
       this.isError = isError
   }
}

public class TestEnum {
    public String method(AnEnum anEnum) {
         if( anEnum.isError() ) {
              return "An Error";
         }
         return "Not An Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly of interest [how to test enum types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079700/how-to-test-enum-types). Also [data-driven-testing](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html) may be helpful, and not only for your enum but for cases which require it.

Comment: What is the point of testing getters and setters? Are you testing Java? Limit your test to things with actual logic in it. See [Should unit tests be written for getter and setters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6197370/5221149)

Comment: This is not about to test setters and getters. 

It is about to test all possible combination in your code. Should we test all combinations or should we test just 2 combinations 

( in the example your can have 100% code coverage with only 2 combinations while your code can have a lot more combinations )

Comment: Thanks for the accept ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be using [ParametrizedTests](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/), like:

```
@DataProvider
public static Object[][] provideEnumasAndExpectedErrorResult() {
  return new Object[][] {
    { AnEnum.A, true },
    { AnEnum.B, false }
  };
}

@Test
@UseDataProvider( "provideEnumasAndExpectedErrorResult" )
public void testEnumErrors( AnEnum enumConstant, boolean expectedResult expectedResult ) {
  assertThat( enumConstant.isError(), is(expectedResult));
```

That allows you to write down all your enums and the expected results in a  (somehow) cleaner way.

Comment: I apologize if you already knew, but depending on your licenses restrictions, you could also use these 2 extensions which make thinks cleaner and more elegant: [zohhak](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak) (LGPL 3.0) & [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams) (Apache 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

Data-driven tests are great with Spock:

```
class AnEnumSpec extends Specification {

    def "has correct error status"() {
        expect:
        result == anEnum.isError

        where:
        anEnum   | result
        AnEnum.A | true
        AnEnum.B | false
        AnEnum.C | false
        AnEnum.D | true
    }
}
```