# Asserting Java enum values and fields with AssertJ

Tags: java, assertj

Given a simple enum like this:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum PaymentMethod {

    CREDITCARD(1),
    PAYPAL(2),
    APPLE_PAY(3),
    GOOGLE_PAY(4);

    private final long id;
}
```

How can I write a JUnit test with AssertJ assertions which checks that the enum values **and their fields** are exactly as defined in the enum? So that in the end the test checks for each payment type:

- Does payment type exist in the enum?
- Does payment type X have id Y?

My current apporach works but feels a bit cumbersome. I'm pretty sure that AssertJ provides easier statements but I haven't found a solution yet.

````java
class PaymentTypeTest {

    private static final Map<Long, PaymentType> expectedPaymentTypes = new HashMap<>();

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        expectedPaymentTypes.put(1L, CREDITCARD);
        expectedPaymentTypes.put(2L, PAYPAL);
        expectedPaymentTypes.put(3L, APPLE_PAY);
        expectedPaymentTypes.put(4L, GOOGLE_PAY);    
    }

    @Test
    void should_contain_exact_values() {
        for (Map.Entry<Long, PaymentType> entry : expectedPaymentTypes.entrySet()) {
            final PaymentType paymentType = entry.getValue();
            assertThat(paymentType.getId()).isEqualTo(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: The point is that this enum is used in multiple projects and the id must not change. If someone changed, for example, the id of `CREDITCARD` to `11`, then this must be detected by the test before it gets deployed to the depenendent projects which use this enum. Also, if someone removes a payment type...

Comment: I suppose the enum cordinal must not change. If two services are communicating then the ordinal should point to the same enum value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079700/how-to-test-enum-types

Comment: this does not look that bad :) however, you'd need to not forget to update the test when new enum value is added. to deal with this you might add another test that checks that the size of `expectedPaymentTypes` is the same as the number of enum values

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of separating the test data away from the test class, because when reading the (failing) test method, I then have to move to another place to see what is actually expected. So I would personally do an `assertThat( Arrays.stream(enums.values).map(value -> Pair.of(v.name(), value.getId()).containsExactly( Pair.of(...), Pair.of(...));`

Answer (score 2):

JUnit 5 [parameterized tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) with a [`@CsvSource`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-CsvSource) could help:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
  "CREDITCARD, 1",
  "PAYPAL, 2",
  "APPLE_PAY, 3",
  "GOOGLE_PAY, 4"
})
void getId_should_return_expected_id(PaymentType paymentType, long id) {
  assertThat(paymentType.getId()).isEqualTo(id);
}
```

To make sure that all Enum values are tested, the mappings can be defined as a [`@MethodSource`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-MethodSource) and one more test can enforce the full coverage:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("mappings")
void getId_should_return_expected_id(PaymentType paymentType, long id) {
  assertThat(paymentType.getId()).isEqualTo(id);
}

@Test
void all_values_should_be_tested() {
  List<PaymentType> values = mappings() // same mappings used above
    .map(arguments -> arguments.get()[0])
    .map(PaymentType.class::cast)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

  assertThat(values).contains(PaymentType.values());
}

static Stream<Arguments> mappings() {
  return Stream.of(
    arguments(CREDITCARD, 1L),
    arguments(PAYPAL, 2L),
    arguments(APPLE_PAY, 3L),
    arguments(GOOGLE_PAY, 4L)
  );
}
```